# Odd Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, ef-core-2.0, mysql-5.7

I have an odd one. I cannot create a table using the following:

The **table Users already exists in the DB**, only UserTimeZones is to be added, and it fails.

```
 CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `AccessFailedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EmailConfirmed` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `NormalizedUserName` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NormalizedEmail` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserNameIndex` (`NormalizedUserName`),
  KEY `EmailIndex` (`NormalizedEmail`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `UserTimeZones` (
    `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `UserId` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `TimeZoneOffsetInSeconds` int NOT NULL,
    `LastUpdatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_UserTimeZones` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_UserTimeZones_Users_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `Users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

Here is what the status shows:

> ### ------------------------ LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 2018-11-09 11:26:44 0x7f832c523700 Error in foreign key constraint of
>   table fifty/UserTimeZones:
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `Users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ):
>
> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced
>   columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and
>   the referenced table do not match for constraint.
>
> Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in tables
>   created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables cannot
>   be referenced by such columns in new tables.
>
> Please refer to
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

So I have the classic "Cannot add foreign key constraint".

What I have tried:

- Placing the Users.Id column as first column : doesn't change anything
- The column types are the same, the engines too...
- Applying the migration without data in the DB -> it works
- Running the script in a DB without data -> still doesn't work...

What is the problem?

Not sure it matters but I use entity framework core.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dZsyQBAbrgdQTnwNGjQvVB/2).

Comment: Just updated the code snippet, does it work for you ?

Comment: Yes, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dZsyQBAbrgdQTnwNGjQvVB/4).

Comment: interesting. what are my options in this case ?

Comment: Is the script executed through EF Core or directly on the database?.

Comment: on the DB, using DBeaver. From a fresh DB, this script doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183372/discussion-between-dyesdyes-and-wchiquito).

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> Foreign key definitions for InnoDB tables are subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns.  However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns  are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

But oddly the index seems to be needed on the referencing table:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-keys-examples

So try adding an index on your table

```
CREATE TABLE `UserTimeZones` (
    `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `UserId` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `TimeZoneOffsetInSeconds` int NOT NULL,
    `LastUpdatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_UserTimeZones` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    INDEX userid_ind (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_UserTimeZones_Users_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `Users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

Note: this is what the error message says.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no luck, it's still failing. And the Status is the same.